# SQL Select substring if delimiter exists else give full string

Tags: sql, regex, string, substring, delimiter

I'm trying to select the first part of a string with a delimiter that doesn't always exist.  I have the below `SUBSTRING` function that works great when the delimiter is present, but doesn't return anything when it isn't  i.e. the query below

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(sc.location +'/',0, CHARINDEX('/', sc.location)) FROM sc
```

yields `Tower #1` for the value `Tower #1/Room #3`, but `NULL` if the input is just `Tower #5`

Is there a way to return the full string if the delimiter does not exist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the `CASE` To the `select`. You can try as ,

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', sc.location) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(sc.location +'/',0, CHARINDEX('/', sc.location))
          ELSE sc.location END
FROM sc
```

Comment: Oh nice yea I also thought after a moment "why can't i Just always have a delimiter?" So this works too, idk if it is as good though `SUBSTRING(sc.location +'/',0, CHARINDEX('/', sc.location + '/'))`

Comment: This construct is too long.. are there any simpler form?

Comment: Add "END" before the "FROM sc" in Oracle SQL
(details at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate, a little simpler.

```
replace( left( email, patindex( '%@%', email+'@' ) ), '@', '')
```

This example will extract the name part of an email address, taking everything up to the ampersand then removing the ampersand.  If no ampersand, the appended ampersand means you get it all.